# How to translate menus that are made in views?

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I'm having hard time translating my menu to other languages, when I try to translate menus that I made with views I confront with "You are not authorized to access this page." Is there any easy way to translate such kind of menus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to not generate menu items with views. Just give it a path and create menu items manually which point to the appropriate path. If you need to have a speaking URL, create URL-Aliases for it in each language. This does the trick, usually.

Comment: Thanks, it was really painful and I didn't know how others are doing it so I used some dirty javascript codes to fix it until I find a solution, now I'm happy that I've found a solution!